# Apache2 DirectoryIndex Issue

Tags: ssl, apache2, indexing, directoryindex

I am a little stuck and am sure that this is a trivial problem, but just can't seem to find the right solution.

I have a local development server running apache2 w/mod_ssl & mod_rewrite.
I created a self-signed cert and added the respective virtual host directive for *:443.
The issue I seem to be having is that now that I have the SSL side of things working properly. And when I say properly, I mean that I can go to the https url of my site (e.g. https://dev.mysite/) without adding index.php and it pulls up the index.php just fine.

But when I go to the regular http url of the site, I have to type in the index.php to see the site. (e.g. http://dev.mysite/index.php)

I tried adding a DirectoryIndex directive to the *:80 block, but this still doesn't appear to work.

Below is the virtual host file contents if that helps at all;

```
ServerName dev.mysite

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/bsah_dev/mysite

    <Directory />
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/bsah_dev/mysite/>
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/bsah_dev/mysite

    SSLEngine On

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/bsah_dev/mysite>
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    RewriteEngine on
                    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [NC]
                    RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
            </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    SSLOptions +StrictRequire

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you understand what all of the directives in your `:80` configuration are doing?  If not, remove the ones that you don't understand/need until you've simplified the problem.  Start simple, then make complicated as needed.

Comment: If I understood them, I wouldn't be here asking for help when I inadvertently did something wrong. We all learn by trial & error and reading docs. Ya know?

Comment: I figured it out. It seems that the DirectoryIndex directive should be outside of the <Directory > block.

Including it in both the *:80 & *:443 the same way remedied that issue.

Comment: (This topic is probably more suitable for serverfault.com, you might want to get an account there, if the question is closed and migrated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments on your configuration, which may help you fix this problem:

```
<Directory />
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

That's quite unusual: normally, you wouldn't grant access to anything for the root directory (of your machine, not your document root). See the [Directory documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory), which suggests using this:

```
<Directory />
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

This should work as expected in your configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/bsah_dev/mysite/>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

(This being said, `index.php` will only be used if there's no `index.html` or `index.htm` found first.)

The [DirectoryIndex documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) says it can be placed in "server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess" (see "Context"). It also works within the `Directory` directive (and such values will override the values you'd find at the `VirtualHost` or server level).

This rule, in the HTTPS section doesn't make sense:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/bsah_dev/mysite>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [NC]
                RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

You're using a rewrite rule to redirect to the equivalent `https://` URL. However, this rule is in the section where SSL is enabled, so you're redirecting from `https://` to `https://`, not from `http://`.

Comment: Bruno, I would like to thank you for that rather detailed explanation. I apologize for replying so late, but it still will be extremely helpful going forward. Apache config is definitely something not to be taken lightly and I also know that it has a rather healthy learning curve too. So, with that, again, I thank you.